# (UIAElementArray) elements() is slow

Tags: ios-ui-automation

It takes 4 sec to execute. Is it normal?
I'm developing a search method, that crawls trough the element tree, but in each iteration when I call an element's elements() method, it holds for 4 sec. Having 15 nodes in the tree, it takes a minute!
Any idea on how to find an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the methods on `UIATarget` to decrease the default timeout (5 seconds), for example `pushTimeout(0.5)`.